# Scrolling a page in Chrome suddenly discards all mouse-wheel actions

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, mouse, scrolling

I recently upgraded my Chrome browser to **Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)** 2-3 days ago. I noticed that when I visit a long web-page, if I scroll on the page more than twice in each direction, the scroll-bar just freezes up.

The tab no longer accepts my mouse wheel rotations, or the wheel-click. I can still use keyboard to navigate. LMB/RMB work fine. Just the scrolling action from the mice is ignored.

Everything works fine again when I reload the tab. Is it a known bug? Could it be some faulty extension?

---

### UPDATE

After disabling all extensions, with the `--disable-extensions` flag; this behaviour is still being observed. However, this time it was not triggering with the second scroll action, but completely random. On some pages, it is happening if I reach the end of page, on others if I switch to another tab and come back; and yet others where it is inactive from the beginning.

The behaviour is not the same even on same pages. If I close and reopen a tab; it might behave differently from last time.

Comment: "Could it be some faulty extension?" Well disable your extensions to find out ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Updated above.

Comment: Same happens to me on 65.0.3325.181 (under Ubuntu 16.04.4)

Comment: Same for me on 65.0.3325.181 (under Ubuntu 16.04.4)

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a known bug that might be fixed in Chrome Canary (and hence the upcoming release version). See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=835827 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=835735 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=833254

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: Please write whatever fits best as an answer. Don't just copy-paste the links. Extract information from them that helps in solving the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what should be added, here. This is a known bug and is tracked in the Chromium bug tracker, as is expected. I'm not sure what other useful answer there could be. Basically, the question is a bug report and belongs in the chromium bug tracker and not here on superuser. The answer is that Chrome has that bug.